# how to send the local file using splunk forwarder docker image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, splunk

```
    splunkuniversalforwarder:
        image: splunk/universalforwarder
        environment:
            - SPLUNK_START_ARGS=--accept-license
            - SPLUNK_FORWARD_SERVER=ops-splunkhead02.dop.sfdc.net:9997
            - SPLUNK_USER=root
            - SPLUNK_PASSWORD=xxxx
        ports:
            - 9997:9997
```

I store the log flie in `/var/logs/serviceLog.log` (Not in the container but in the local machine)

I don't see the parameter to pass the file path;;; Seems like the splunk forwarder is running in the background and I just realized I never pass the log source variable to the container!

Does anyone perhaps have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to add `SPLUNK_ADD` directive to your sample to specify the behavior.

you can use docker image [related documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/dayreiner/splunk-universalforwarder/) to see multiples examples.

I wrote a ready to use [splunk docker bootstrap](https://github.com/boly38/splunk-docker-bootstrap) project that will use `SPLUNK_ADD` to collect logs.

a short extract:

```
SPLUNK_ADD_2: 'monitor /var/log/app2/ -index docker_file -sourcetype _json'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using following configuration for Splunk forwarder:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  splunkforwarder:
    image: splunk/universalforwarder:9.0.6
    environment:
      - SPLUNK_START_ARGS=--accept-license
      - SPLUNK_PASSWORD="securePAssssw()ord"
    # this is used as Linux server name when sending logs to the server
    hostname: myHostName
    volumes:
      - ./configurations:/opt/splunkforwarder-etc/system/local/
      # access to server logs defined in inputs.conf
      # ensure that docker has permission to mentioned directories and files
      - /var/log/myApp/:/var/log/myApp/:ro
```

and put splunk configurations into `./configuratio` directory, such as `deploymentclient.conf`, `inputs.conf`

Also recommend to mount volume for `/opt/splunkforwarder/var/lib/splunk/` so data won't be lost after container restart/redeployment